# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'theme_style'

Tags: python, kivy

I have been encountering a problem, while making a kivy app that uses theme manager:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'theme_style'

And I don't know why it happens, what am I doing wrong here? And some tips on making my code better would not hurt.

```py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp

Builder.load_string("""
                    
<menu>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 3
        Label:
            text: ""
            size: 200, 125
            size_hint: None, None # <---
        AsyncImage:
            source: 'kulunvalvonta.png'
            size: 200, 150         
            size_hint: None, None # <---
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.1, 'center_y': .5}
        Label:
            text: ""
            size: 200, 125
            size_hint: None, None # <---
        Button:
            size: 200, 125
            size_hint: None, None # <---
            text: "Login"
            on_press: root.manager.current = "login"
        Button:
            size: 200, 125
            size_hint: None, None # <---
            text: "Register"
            on_press: root.manager.current = "register"
<login>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 3
        
        Label:
            text: ""
      
""")
class menu(Screen):
    pass
class sovellus(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "BlueGray"  
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    

    
    def build(self):      
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(menu(name='menu'))
        return Builder.load_file("login.py")
        
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sovellus().run()
```

Comment: Post the full traceback so we can see which line fails.

Comment: You likely need to do the `super().__init__(**kwargs)` _before_ you attempt to use variables in the instance.

Answer (score 1):

move the theme_cls to build method

```py
    def build(self):      
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(menu(name='menu'))
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "BlueGray"  
        return Builder.load_file("login.py")
```